# How to I get rid of extra / in http://localhost:8080/test/ in Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9, jetty-8

I want any user trying to access http://localhost:8080/test/ to be redirected to http://localhost:8080/test. I want to remove the extra `'/'` after test.

I tried writing this in rewrite rules but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hi -- could you post the rules you have tried, even if they don't work. Someone might spot something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `contextPath` is `/test` then the extra slash is required to satisfy the context path rules of both the servlet spec and the URI / http resource declarations of the various RFCs.

If you set your web application, handler, context, etc with the "context path" of `/test` then you'll want to switch to using `/` (the root context) and having a servlet url-pattern of `/test` (exactly named `/test`).

Comment: how do i do that ? how do i serve from / ? The webapps folder has a war file named test.war and inside the war file there is WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: in my web.xml i could do this 

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>HttpReceiver</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>myclass</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HttpReceiver</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    

but i how to i get the final url to be http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: Either use a [context xml deployable](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html), or simply call your webapp `ROOT.war`.

Comment: Thanks i figured it out created root folder in webapps!

Comment: Thank you soo much